# how to print items in an array like print(* List) in python?

Tags: arrays, swift

In python, we can print the items of a list(like array in swift) in this way:

```
Numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(* Numbers)
```

Then the result is:

> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

[image]

Is there something like that in Swift to print an array?

Comment: Omer's answer can be modified to give a comma-separated string like you get in Python: `print(arr.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", "))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(arr.map {"\($0) "}.reduce("",+)  )
```

Output :

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: If you modify your answer to use `arr.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ", ")`, it would exactly replicate the Python output, which seems to be what OP is asking for.